# Solr core creation on HDFS failing

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs

I am trying to make Solr 4.7.2  work with HDFS (using Hadoop 2.4.1).

Here is `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<config>
<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_47</luceneMatchVersion>
<lockType>hdfs</lockType>
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
<writeLockTimeout>20000</writeLockTimeout>
<commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.HdfsDirectoryFactory">
  <str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://localhost:54310/solr</str>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">1</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.write.enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>
</directoryFactory>
<requestHandler name='standard' class=
'solr.StandardRequestHandler' default='true' />
<requestHandler name='/update' class=
'solr.UpdateRequestHandler' />
<requestHandler name='/admin/' class=
'org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers' />
<admin>
<defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
</admin>
</config>
```

Once I start Solr server, it throws the exception:

```
hdp1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
```

I tried to debug and found the following error in jetty log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: 

NativeFSLock@hdfs:/localhost:54310/solr/hdp1/data/index/HdfsDirectory@1d5821fa lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@hdfs:/localhost:54310/solr/hdp1/data/index-write.lock: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/localhost:54310/solr/hdp1/data/index/HdfsDirectory@1d5821fa lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@hdfs:/localhost:54310/solr/hdp1/data/index-write.lock (No such file or directory)
```

It's able to create directories on HDFS, but somehow failing while creating/accessing
the index.

Comment: i am facing same issue ,when i try creating index on only one node everything works fine the moment i add an another node in the cluster and try create a new index with sharding as 2 it gives me time out error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs.